# Oracle PL/SQL - How to create a package local alias to a procedure w/out creating a public synonym?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm referencing the same single stored procedure in another package many times.
Instead of using `pkg_name.` for every single one, I was wondering if you could create a Package Level synonym to the other procedure?
This would also give it a bit of inheritance.

Basically, I'm trying to mimic `static import` or `extends` in Java.

## Instead of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg
IS
   PROCEDURE test
   IS
   BEGIN
      some_name_utils.do_lots_of_stuff()
   END;
BEGIN
END;
/
```

## I'd like to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg
IS
   SYNONYM do_lots_of_stuff FOR some_name_utils.do_lots_of_stuff;

   PROCEDURE test;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg
IS
   PROCEDURE test
   IS
   BEGIN
      do_lots_of_stuff()
   END;
BEGIN
END;
/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I could say that I agree with this approach; if the other package changes, you have to remember to update it here as well. However, the following would serve the purpose you are seeking.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg
IS
   PROCEDURE do_lots_of_stuff
   IS
   BEGIN
      some_name_utils.do_lots_of_stuff();
   END;

   PROCEDURE test
   IS
   BEGIN
      do_lots_of_stuff;
   END;
BEGIN
END;
/
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now. Also, you would have to change it both places anyway. Was just hoping for a one-liner for it. If nobody comes up w/ another approach, I'll mark yours as the solution.